# RxJava: How to transform a Single<Response> to Single<List<Item>>

Tags: android, kotlin, lambda, repository, rx-java

Let's say I have an Android app with the following Repository class to fetch objects from API:

```
override fun fetchOrderById(orderId: Long): Single<List<ItemRow>> {
    return api.fetchOrderByIdObservable(orderId)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .map { orderResponse ->
                orderResponse.items.map { deliveryItem ->
                    deliveryItem.asItemRow()
                }
            }
}

override fun fetchOrders(): Single<OrdersResponse> {
    return api.fetchOrdersObservable()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
}

override fun fetchAllOrders(): Single<List<ItemRow>> {
     // TODO
}
```

With the following data class:

```
class OrdersResponse(@SerializedName("orders") val orders: List<Long>)
class OrderResponse(@SerializedName("items") val items: List<DeliveryItem>)
```

Right now, I can use fetchOrderById to get all delivery items (ItemRow) for a certain orderId as a domain object in my app to show in a list. How can I use fetchOrders, which returns a list of orderIds to get all delivery items for all orders? Which operators would be useful here? I played around with FlatMap, but could not get it to work. Link to articles would be ++ too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

operators you need: `switchMap()`, `flatMap()`, `fromArray()`, `toList()`, `map()` it's gonna be something like this:

```
fun fetchAllOrders(): Observable<List<ItemRow>> {
    return fetchOrders()
        .toObservable()
        .switchMap { ordersResponse ->
            Observable.fromIterable(ordersResponse.orders)
                .flatMap {orderId -> fetchOrderById(orderId).toObservable() }
                .toList()
                .toObservable()
        }
        .map { list -> list.flatten() }
    }
```

Comment: Hmmm thanks for the response, but this one is not working. In .`flatMap {orderId -> fetchOrderById(orderId) }`, a List<Long>  (list of orderIds) is passed, not a Long (orderId)! :/

Comment: @sorry_I_wont there was typo error, please see edited answer. You need to pass `ordersResponse.orders` in to `Observable.fromArray`

Comment: I don't think the problem is typo, I have this error in switchMap body:

`Type mismatch.
Required:
ObservableSource<out (???..???)>!
Found:
Single<(Mutable)List<List<ItemRow>!>!>!
Type mismatch.
Required:
ObservableSource<out TypeVariable(R)!>!
Found:
Single<(Mutable)List<List<ItemRow>!>!>!`

Comment: Edited again, add `.toObservable()` after `fetchOrders()`

Comment: Thanks, this time it compiled! This is weird, what's the difference between "calling toObservable on fetchOrders()" vs. "having fetchOrders() return an observable instead of Single"?
Because when I change it fetchOrders() to return an Observable<OrdersResponse> instead of Single, it won't work, but they should be the same thing!!

Comment: it depends on how do you do `change it fetchOrders() to return an Observable<OrdersResponse> `

Comment: Sorry scratch that!

Thanks, I think it's closer now, but not yet! now it says "Not enough information to infer type variable R" on switchMap (gotta love rxjava errors) and also this time I get something similar to the other error:

Type mismatch.
Required:
ObservableSource<out (???..???)>!
Found:
Single<List<ItemRow>>
Type mismatch.
Required:
ObservableSource<out TypeVariable(R)!>!
Found:
Single<List<ItemRow>>

but on fetchOrderById(orderId) in flatMap!

Comment: try to add `.toObservable()` after `fetchOrderById(orderId)` too

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately! Now I get an error on the whole 

                Observable.fromArray(ordersResponse.orders)
                            .flatMap {orderId -> fetchOrderById(orderId).toObservable() }
                            .toList()

Type mismatch.
Required:
ObservableSource<out (???..???)>!
Found:
Single<(Mutable)List<List<ItemRow>!>!>!
Type mismatch.
Required:
ObservableSource<out TypeVariable(R)!>!
Found:
Single<(Mutable)List<List<ItemRow>!>!>!
Type mismatch.
Required:
Long
Found:
List<Long>

Sorry I'm new to all dis!

Comment: Would it help if the return types are Observable instead of Single? I'd be fine with that

Comment: I was able to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

This worked eventually:

```
    public fun fetchAllItems(): Observable<List<ItemRow>> {
    return networkService.api.fetchOrdersObservable()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .flatMap { orderResponse ->  Observable.just(orderResponse.orders) }
            .flatMapIterable { id -> id }
            .flatMap { id -> fetchOrderById(id) }
            .flatMapIterable { itemRow -> itemRow }
            .toList()
}
```